# Theory behind CountRoots

Tags: equation-solving, complex, implementation-details

According to this [page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountRoots.html), one can compute the number of zeros of a meromorphic function over an interval in Mathematica.

I am working with univariate functions of x, which are meromorphic elementary functions.

e.g. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}+2$ over $(0,4\pi]$
[image]

By accident, I have found that CountRoots[0,{x,a,b}]=0, which is obviously wrong.
[image]

I would like to confirm that I can rely on the command CountRoots[f,{x,a,b}] to get the number of zeros of a non-zero meromorphic elementary functions in an interval.
So, I would like to know the process behind the program.
I have googled about the theory behind the process and have found out this paper:
[**On locating the zeros and poles of a meromorphic
function---Haotian Chen**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.09047.pdf)
.

From Theorem 1 on p.3, one can compute the total number of zeros and poles of a meromorphic
function inside a contour $C$.

By [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), one can compute the difference between the number of zeros and the number of poles inside a contour $C$.

As a result, one can compute the number of zeros and also the number of poles
inside a contour $C$ respectively.

Also, we can see that the theory is not applicable to zero function.

> **Question:** How does Mathematica compute the number of zeros of meromorphic
> function over a real interval instead of a contour?

Comment: Yes, I think the answer should be $\infty$ because $f(x)=0$ has infinite number of roots by convention.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this may be why: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The limits found in `"IntervalRootsOptions" /. ("ReduceOptions" /. SystemOptions[]`) suggest limitations on the reliability of `CountRoots[]`. (See ``Trace[CountRoots[Sin[x^2], {x, -1, 2}],  _Reduce`IntervalRoots ]`` for relevance of this remark.)